# How does FAST detector initially find edge candidates? How do any of the edge and feature detectors intially find candidates?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, signal-processing, feature-extraction, feature-detection

I've been reading up on how FAST detector work on paper by Edward Rosten and others interpretations of it online on how the algorithm identify edge by comparing the candidate pixel I_p against the points around it + threshold through learned decisions tree and say if it's an edge or not.

I get that part but what the all the explanation I've been looking at has been missing is how the algorithm initially finds this Key point candidate initially. This seems to be the case not only for FAST but any other key points detector and feature descriptors. All the papers and explanation of feature extractors/descriptor focuses on is how they are identified once they find candidates and does not explain how they initially go about finding the possible key points to look at.

I've looked at the source code on OpenCV here
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/features2d/src/fast.cpp but honestly the code is pretty cryptic. I think what it is doing is just doing is a sliding window across the image by the FAST window or kernel size for the detector ring, which is 6 across it's diameter and just moving along to find some candidates.

Is this how the detectors find candidates? Does it usually use sliding window? Does it use some other approach? Does other detector use different ways to initially find candidates? Are there other ways or algorithms to find edge or key point candidates?

Comment: Yes, these detectors always apply to each pixel.